# ZeroMQ Loosing subscribe connection

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I am using ZeroMQ `PUB/SUB` with one publisher and multiple subscribers. My **`PUB`**-side is `send()`-ing every 10 sec. At first all subscribe works fine. But later the connection is broken. How to alive connection without broken. Am using ZMQ npm 2.15.0 version.

```
const zmq = require("zmq");
const sock = zmq.socket("sub");
sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000");

sock.on('message', function (topic, message) {
console.log('received a message ', message) );
console.log('received a message related to:', topic.toString());
});
```

Comment: in this above code am subscribing topic and receiving data for all subscribed topic but after some time publishing working but subscribe not working.
////Code for subscribe topic/////
    sock.subscribe(response.symbols[i]); //Topic am subscribing

Comment: Kindly **post the complete MCVE-code** for both the **`PUB`**-side and the **`SUB`**-side.